# django testing class based view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-testing

I have a Class based view defined as:

```
class Myview(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def post():
      #.......
```

to test this view i tried this

```
class MyViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='soos@i.com', password='vvggtt')

    def view_test(self):
        # Create an instance of a POST request.
        request = self.factory.post('/my-url/')
        request.user = self.user

        response = MyView(request)
        print (response,"**")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

But this gives this error.

```
    response = MyView(request)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I understand why this error is coming (cinstructor of MyView has 2 ars) but how do i remove it? i couldnt get the details on searching.

Comment: Have you implemented your own `__init__` method in `MyView`? If so could you post it?

Comment: Normally `request` wouldn't be passed to the class constructor; see `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view`

Comment: @user234461 no i didnt implement __init__ in myview

Comment: @user234461 all i want is log in with a user and hit a post request and check if the response is correct

Comment: yeah well `MyView(request)` is wrong. The constructor doesn't take a request. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py

Comment: Which method of `View` expects a `request`? The answer is right there in the function arguments - use the source, Luke.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unit test methods inside django's class based views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645780/how-to-unit-test-methods-inside-djangos-class-based-views)

Comment: @user234461 i figured that after following the link you gave. but now i am gettinga another error  `list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'nth_term'` . i am creating the post request as         `request = self.factory.post('/my-url/',
                                    data={'nth_term': 5},
                                    content_type='application/json')`

Comment: this worked when i removed the `content_type`

Answer (score 3):

we can use django test `client`

```
from django.test import Client

class MyViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='soos@i.com', password='vvggtt')

    def view_test(self):
        # Create an instance of a POST request.
        self.client.login(username="jacob", password="vvggtt")
        data = {'name': 'test name'}
        res = self.client.post('/my-url/', data)
        print(res)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/advanced/):

```
# Use this syntax for class-based views.
response = MyView.as_view()(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
response = MyView(request=request)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a section of the Django docs called [Testing Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/advanced/#testing-class-based-views) which addresses this:

> In order to test class-based views outside of the request/response cycle you must ensure that they are configured correctly, by calling setup() after instantiation.

So in your case this looks something like:

```
    def view_test(self):
        # Create an instance of a POST request.
        request = self.factory.post('/my-url/')
        request.user = self.user

        my_view = MyView()
        my_view.setup(request)
        response = my_view.post(request)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```